# Can we express $\cos(4\theta)$ using only cosine?

Tags: trigonometry

We can express $\cos(3\theta)$ using only cosines, can we do that with $4\theta$?

Comment: Yes. Have you tried using the double-angle $\,\cos\,$ formula twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cos ({4\theta}) = 2{\cos^2 ({2\theta})} - 1 = 2(2 \cos^2 \theta -1)^2 - 1$$

Answer (score 4):

For all $n\in\Bbb N$, $\cos nt$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\cos t$.
These polynomials are [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).
As an example
$$\cos4t=2\cos^22t-1=2(2\cos^2t-1)^2-1$$
etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=\cos\theta$ and $s\sin\theta$
\begin{align*}
\cos 4\theta+i\sin4\theta&=(c+is)^4\\
&=c^4+4ic^3s-6c^2s^2-4ics^3+s^4
\end{align*}

Comparing the real parts,

\begin{align*}
\cos 4\theta&=c^4-6c^2s^2+s^4\\
&=c^4-6c^2(1-c^2)+(1-c^2)^2\\
&=8c^4-8c^2+1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\cos4t+\cos2t=2\cos3t\cos t$$

Now can you express $\cos3t,\cos2t$ in terms of $\cos t$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course

$$ cos(4\theta)=2\cos ^2 (2\theta)-1$$

$$2[2\cos ^2 (\theta)-1 ]^2-1 $$

$$2[4\cos ^4(\theta)-4\cos^2(\theta)+1 ]-1 $$

$$8\cos ^4 (\theta)-8\cos^2(\theta)+1 $$